# Very unexpected return in a python function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

In my introduction to programming class, we had the following function in the exam however the last output is very unexpected.

```
def r2d2(a):
    b = True
    for k in range(len(a)):
        b = b and bb8(a,k)
    return b
def bb8(a,k):
    a[k] = a[k]-1
    return a[k] >= 0
```

In this program we set a to:`a=[1,2,3,4]` and call the following:

```
print(r2d2(a))
print(a)
print(r2d2(a))
print(a)
```

the program output for the first 3 commands are:

```
True
[0, 1, 2, 3]
False
```

which are expected. however, the fourth output is `[-1, 1, 2, 3]`. Isn't it supposed to be `[-1,0,1,2]`?

I tried manipulating the code to understand the reason however I couldn't come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confused about how the statement `b and bb8(a, k)` is evaluated.

For optimization purposes, Python will never even run the `bb8` function if `b == False`, because then the statement must also be false. Therefore, once `b` becomes `False` , the `bb8` function will never be run again, so no more values in `a` are decremented. It is as if the function has ended at this point.